# Ansible: Can you register the Linux banner without logging in?

Tags: ansible, conditional-statements, banner

I'm trying to capture the linux banner you see before you login to a Linux server - using Ansible. I don't want to login to the server, just get the banner. I was hoping to use register to save it, then use part of it's contents as a conditional for which tasks to run.

Is this possible?

I originally tried to just run a remote command and capture the output, but I only get the output of the command and not the banner so it's a little more tricky to do than I first thought.

I.e.: a standard banner:

```
WARNING : Unauthorized access to this system is forbidden and will be
prosecuted by law. By accessing this system, you agree that your actions
may be monitored if unauthorized usage is suspected.
MANAGED by SYSTEM-A
```

So if I find `MANAGED by SYSTEM-A` in the banner, I run specific tasks and specific host variables. If it isn't managed by `system-a`, I run the same tasks but use different host variables.

This would form part of a set of pre-tasks within Ansible before the main playbooks and roles are run.

What I'm seeing is the banner is probably discarded as rubbish by Ansible but there may be an output plugin I could use to save the contents?

Hopefully I've explained what I'm trying to do and someone has maybe done this previously.

**** UPDATE ****

> I tested the fix offered but was unable to get it to work.
>
> Instead, I used nc (netcat) to check the port of the servers for the
> version of SSH in use. As we are migrating to a different login tool,
> the version of SSH was for a very specific product and it was easy to
> identify servers using the different SSH version. So I just took the
> result of the `nc` command and used that to dynamically create an
> ansible inventory of and put them into groups of [Product] vs
> [nonProduct] along with the specific connection variables for each
> type of SSH.
>
> If anyone would like to see what that looked like and how I got it to
> work, just post a message here.

**** UPDATE END ****

Comment: "_If anyone would like to see what that looked like and how I got it to work_", yes please. Can share it here in a separate answer? Or even create a new question and answer it itself?

Answer (score 3):

Just `ignore_unreachable`:

```
---
- name: Simple playbook to show banner
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  - name: Try to connect
    ansible.builtin.ping:
    register: result
    ignore_unreachable: yes

  - name: Show output
    ansible.builtin.debug:
      var: result
```

I broke my own connection to show the result:

```
$ ansible-playbook get_banner.yml --limit Client1

PLAY [Test playbook] *****************************************************************

TASK [Try to connect] ****************************************************************
fatal: [Client1]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: WARNING\n\nThis is JAX Test VM.  Don't break it.\nansible@client1: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).", "skip_reason": "Host Client1 is unreachable", "unreachable": true}

TASK [Show output] *******************************************************************
ok: [Client1] => {
    "result": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: WARNING\n\nThis is JAX Test VM.  Don't break it.\nansible@client1: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).",
        "skip_reason": "Host Client1 is unreachable",
        "unreachable": true
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************
Client1                    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the distribution, but the banner is by default located in:
`/etc/issue` or `/etc/issue.net`

You could run a pretask like:

```
- name: Slurp the banner
  ansible.builtin.slurp:
    src: /etc/issue
  register: banner
```

And then introduce your conditionals based on `banner` output

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm not able to login to the server to get to /etc/issue. That's why I need to capture this info before I can login.

I want to capture the banner as it would appear during an SSH login. This is because we have different methods to login to different servers and I'm trying to develop a way to use the correct login method depending on the banner output.

so pre-check is the banner (but not logging in, then based on something in the text, Ansible conditionally does "something".

Comment: You will only get the banner of the server when you logged in, what you are looking to do is not possible.

Comment: The/etc/issue file is not used in the same way as the/ETC/MOTD file, the main difference is that when a network user or through a serial port to log on to the system,/etc/issue file content is displayed BEFORE the login prompt, and/etc/ MOTD content appears AFTER the user successfully logs on to the system - In my case, "banner" is /etc/issue.